# Syntax error on token ";", Expression expected after this token in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using this Code in my jsp:

```
<c:if test="<%=box.getPrefs().getBool("PrefOTPEnabled")%>">
        <div class="ChOptPadd_r11 padd_t2">
            <div class="link">

            </div>
        </div>
</c:if>
```

but I got a syntax error: `Syntax error on token ";", Expression expected after this token`

What is wrong with that?

Comment: You may not use scriptlet expressions inside JSP tags. Use the expression language. Pretend as scriptlets didn't exist. You should not use them, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have double quotes. It should be apostrophe  in 'PrefOTPEnabled'.

```
<c:if test="<%=box.getPrefs().getBool('PrefOTPEnabled')%>">
        <div class="ChOptPadd_r11 padd_t2">
            <div class="link">

            </div>
        </div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: why would you use jstl if and then jsp scriptlet tags inside, why not just do the entire if in jsp scriptlets?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <% if (box.getPrefs().getBool("PrefOTPEnabled")){%> 

        <div class="ChOptPadd_r11 padd_t2">
            <div class="link">

            </div>
        </div>
    <%}%>
```